# Extracting numeric objects from list of character objects

Tags: r

I am trying to extract each elements recursivelly individually to place it in a loop function. The items in the expression below from which I get the following objects in a vector. I would like to extract the content of each object which is a numeric. I seem to have significant problems as I have spend over a day attempting this exercise without result. I have used noquote as to get out from the "", however this also does not work as it converts the object in a noquote object. Converting the main object as numeric also does not work, converting the elements within the main object to numeric also does not work.

```
as.vector(paste("q", paste("[[",1:length(q),"]]"), sep="", collapse=","))
[1] "q[[ 1 ]],q[[ 2 ]],q[[ 3 ]],q[[ 4 ]],q[[ 5 ]],q[[ 6 ]],q[[ 7 ]],q[[ 8 ]],q[[ 9 ]],q[[ 10 ]],q[[ 11 ]],q[[ 12 ]],q[[ 13 ]],q[[ 14 ]],q[[ 15 ]],q[[ 16 ]],q[[ 17 ]],q[[ 18 ]],q[[ 19 ]],q[[ 20 ]],q[[ 21 ]]"
```

A shorter example

```
q<-list(c(1,3,5,7,8),c(2,4,6,7,8),c(1,2,5,5,8))
as.vector(paste("q", paste("[[",1:length(q),"]]"), sep="", collapse=","))
[1] "q[[ 1 ]],q[[ 2 ]],q[[ 3 ]]"
```

EDIT:

The desired output without considering the list and resulting from the expression would be as follows possible errors:

```
d<- as.vector(paste("q", paste("[[",1:length(q),"]]"), sep="", collapse=","))
d
[1] "q[[ 1 ]],q[[ 2 ]],q[[ 3 ]]"

d[[1]]
[1] 1 3 5 7 8
d[[2]]
[1] 2 4 6 7 8
d[[3]]
[1] 1 2 5 5 8
```

Comment: What is the desired output for the `q` you have provided?

Comment: Is the problem that you have a character vector `"q[[ 1 ]],q[[ 2 ]],q[[ 3 ]]"` and you would like to parse this to extract the corresponding values of `q`.?

Comment: if so, `lapply(strsplit(d, ",")[[1]], function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))` is one way .... but I would rethink your workflow to try and avoid generating this character string

Comment: Appologies added a solution example, understood reviewing the output thank you

Comment: Are you given character strings like `"q[[ 1 ]],q[[ 2 ]],q[[ 3 ]]"` as well as the list `q`?

Comment: there are over 700 vectors in a list named q as I select some they get reduced to a few. My goal is to reference the list q to the index vector selected. I guess as sugested before I think rethinking how to get the output may be more beneficial as a first though maybe applying mapply may work. Howeber the cabeat is that from the selected list I have to select the min and max values among all  the different vectors which I though I could do this way

Comment: If you have list `q` and indices `idx <- c(1, 2, 3)` and you want the minimum and maximum elements of each, this is as simple as `sapply(q[idx], min)` and `sapply(q[idx], max)`. I think it would be best to rewrite your question stating exactly what you are given and what you want as the output. For instance, it sounds like you want min and max values from some elements of the list, but this isn't mentioned anywhere in the question itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment on your question, it sounds like you want to specify some indices in `q` and then extract the minimum and maximum values from the corresponding vectors. This can be done with `sapply`:

```
idx <- c(1, 2, 3)
sapply(q[idx], min)
# [1] 1 2 1
sapply(q[idx], max)
# [1] 8 8 8
```

Comment: I was working on it with lapply I think your solution is better, many thanks and appologies for a non clearly framed question.